# How to average every 5 rows in a data set-- R

Tags: r

I have reviewed a few similar questions to mine and been unable to understand how or if they apply to my data set.

I have data on a number of students's answers to five questions over eleven different time points. I am hoping to average the students' answers to the questions so their average response can be graphed over time.

Is there a simple way to average every 5 rows?

I'm a beginner and any help would be appreciated!

I have provided my data below:

```
> dput(pulse)
structure(list(ï..Question = structure(c(1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L, 
1L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 8L), .Label = c("Q", "Q10", "Q11_1", "Q11_2", 
"Q11_3", "Q11_4", "Q11_5", "Q12", "Q2", "Q8"), class = "factor"), 
    Type = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("FYS", "SNR"), class = "factor"), Student = c(789331L, 
    789331L, 789331L, 789331L, 789331L, 805933L, 805933L, 805933L, 
    805933L, 805933L, 826523L, 826523L, 826523L, 826523L, 826523L, 
    832929L, 832929L, 832929L, 832929L, 832929L, 838607L, 838607L, 
    838607L, 838607L, 838607L, 841903L, 841903L, 841903L, 841903L, 
    841903L, 843618L, 843618L, 843618L, 843618L, 843618L, 852125L, 
    852125L, 852125L, 852125L, 852125L, 876406L, 876406L, 876406L, 
    876406L, 876406L, 879972L, 879972L, 879972L, 879972L, 879972L, 
    885650L, 885650L, 885650L, 885650L, 885650L, 888712L, 888712L, 
    888712L, 888712L, 888712L, 903303L, 903303L, 903303L, 903303L, 
    903303L, 796882L, 796882L, 796882L, 796882L, 796882L, 827911L, 
    827911L, 827911L, 827911L, 827911L, 830271L, 830271L, 830271L, 
    830271L, 830271L, 831487L, 831487L, 831487L, 831487L, 831487L, 
    834598L, 834598L, 834598L, 834598L, 834598L, 836364L, 836364L, 
    836364L, 836364L, 836364L, 839802L, 839802L, 839802L, 839802L, 
    839802L, 855524L, 855524L, 855524L, 855524L, 855524L, 873527L, 
    873527L, 873527L, 873527L, 873527L, 885409L, 885409L, 885409L, 
    885409L, 885409L, 894218L, 894218L, 894218L, 894218L, 894218L, 
    928026L, 928026L, 928026L, 928026L, 928026L, 932196L, 932196L, 
    932196L, 932196L, 932196L, 955389L, 955389L, 955389L, 955389L, 
    955389L, 956952L, 956952L, 956952L, 956952L, 956952L, 957206L, 
    957206L, 957206L, 957206L, 957206L, 957759L, 957759L, 957759L, 
    957759L, 957759L, 959200L, 959200L, 959200L, 959200L, 959200L, 
    962490L, 962490L, 962490L, 962490L, 962490L, 968728L, 968728L, 
    968728L, 968728L, 968728L, 969005L, 969005L, 969005L, 969005L, 
    969005L, 971179L, 971179L, 971179L, 971179L, 971179L, 976863L, 
    976863L, 976863L, 976863L, 976863L, 981621L, 981621L, 981621L, 
    981621L, 981621L, 952797L, 952797L, 952797L, 952797L, 952797L, 
    965873L, 965873L, 965873L, 965873L, 965873L, 967416L, 967416L, 
    967416L, 967416L, 967416L, 975424L, 975424L, 975424L, 975424L, 
    975424L), Rt1 = c(4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 
    4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, 4, 
    4, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 
    4, 5, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Rt2 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 5, 
    5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
    5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4), Rt3 = c(4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 
    4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 
    3, 1, 4, 1, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 
    4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
    5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4), 
    Rt4 = c(5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, 
    3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 3, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 
    5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    5, 4, 3, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Rt5 = c(3, 
    3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
    4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 
    5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 
    4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    4, 3, 3, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), Rt6 = c(4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 
    5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
    4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 3, 2, 
    3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 2, 
    4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 
    5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 
    4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Rt7 = c(5, 
    2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
    4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
    4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 
    5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 
    2, 3, 4), Rt8 = c(4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 
    4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 
    4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 3, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 
    4, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 
    4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Rt9 = c(4, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
    5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 5, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), Rt10 = c(5, 3, 3, 3, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
    1, 1, 1, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 
    4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 
    3, 2, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4), Rt11 = c(5, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 
    5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 
    4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("ï..Question", 
"Type", "Student", "Rt1", "Rt2", "Rt3", "Rt4", "Rt5", "Rt6", 
"Rt7", "Rt8", "Rt9", "Rt10", "Rt11"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 81L, 82L, 
83L, 84L, 85L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 
105L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 
131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 151L, 
152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 171L, 172L, 
173L, 174L, 175L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 
194L, 195L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 
215L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 
241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 261L, 
262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 281L, 282L, 
283L, 284L, 285L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 
304L, 305L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 321L, 322L, 323L, 324L, 
325L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 
351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 371L, 
372L, 373L, 374L, 375L, 381L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 385L, 391L, 392L, 
393L, 394L, 395L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You want to average the 'Rt' columns?

Comment: @akrun
Hi! I want to average the Q,Q2,Q8,Q10,Q12 rows.

Comment: You said in the description `average every 5 rows`.  It is not clear if you are saying that to average the Q, Q2, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try

```
t(sapply(split(pulse[4:ncol(pulse)], as.integer(gl(nrow(pulse), 5, nrow(pulse)))), colMeans, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or if we need to group based on the first column

```
t(sapply(split(pulse[4:ncol(pulse)], cumsum(pulse[[1]]=="Q")), colMeans, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or if we are grouping based on 'Student'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(pulse)[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE) , by = .(Type, Student), .SDcols = 4:ncol(pulse)]
#   Type Student Rt1  Rt2 Rt3 Rt4 Rt5  Rt6 Rt7 Rt8 Rt9 Rt10 Rt11
# 1:  SNR  789331 3.6 3.80 4.0 4.2 3.4 2.40 3.0 3.2 3.2  3.6  4.0
# 2:  SNR  805933 4.8 4.00 4.0 3.6 3.2 3.20 3.2 3.2 NaN  NaN  3.2
# 3:  SNR  826523 4.4 4.20 4.2 4.4 4.6 4.60 NaN 4.6 NaN  4.2  4.2
# 4:  SNR  832929 3.8 3.80 3.8 4.0 3.6  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
# 5:  SNR  838607 5.0 5.00 5.0 5.0 5.0 4.40 4.2 4.4 3.8  NaN  3.6
# 6:  SNR  841903 3.2 4.20 4.2 NaN 3.6  NaN 4.0 3.4 4.2  NaN  4.6
# 7:  SNR  843618 4.4 4.40 4.6 4.4 4.4 4.40 4.4 4.2 3.6  4.0  4.4
# 8:  SNR  852125 3.2  NaN 3.8 4.0 3.8 3.60 3.6 4.0 NaN  3.4  4.6
# 9:  SNR  876406 3.6 4.00 4.2 4.0 4.0 2.40 2.8 3.8 3.0  3.2  4.2
#10:  SNR  879972 3.8 3.80 3.8 NaN 4.0 4.20 4.0 4.0 4.0  4.0  NaN
#11:  SNR  885650 4.0 4.40 4.0 4.0 4.2 4.00 4.4 4.2 3.8  4.0  NaN
#12:  SNR  888712 4.4 4.00 NaN 4.2 4.4 4.40 4.6 3.8 4.2  4.0  4.6
#13:  SNR  903303 3.6 3.80 4.6 4.0 NaN 3.40 3.8 3.6 3.8  3.6  4.6
#14:  SNR  796882 NaN 4.40 4.0 4.0 2.8 3.60 2.8 1.4 2.2  2.0  4.2
#15:  SNR  827911 NaN 4.20 3.6 NaN 3.4 3.40 NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
#16:  SNR  830271 NaN 4.60 4.8 5.0 5.0 4.40 4.8 NaN 5.0  NaN  5.0
#17:  SNR  831487 NaN 4.40 4.2 4.6 4.4  NaN 4.2 4.6 4.8  4.4  4.6
#18:  SNR  834598 NaN 5.00 3.8 4.0 4.2 4.00 4.0 NaN NaN  4.0  4.2
#19:  SNR  836364 NaN 4.00 4.0 4.0 3.6 3.20 3.6 3.6 3.4  3.4  4.0
#20:  SNR  839802 NaN 3.40 2.0 1.8 4.2 2.20 3.0 4.2 2.8  1.8  4.0
#21:  SNR  855524 NaN 5.00 4.6 4.6 4.2 4.40 4.8 4.0 5.0  4.2  4.6
#22:  SNR  873527 NaN 3.80 3.8 4.2 4.0  NaN 4.2 4.4 NaN  3.8  4.4
#23:  SNR  885409 NaN 4.80 4.6 4.8 4.4 4.40 4.2 4.4 NaN  3.8  3.6
#24:  SNR  894218 NaN 4.40 4.4 4.6 5.0 5.00 5.0 NaN NaN  4.0  5.0
#25:  FYS  928026 NaN 4.60 4.8 NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
#26:  FYS  932196 NaN 3.20 NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN  NaN
#27:  FYS  955389 NaN 5.00 4.6 NaN 4.0  NaN 4.4 4.6 4.4  NaN  NaN
#28:  FYS  956952 NaN 4.20 NaN NaN NaN 3.20 4.4 4.2 NaN  4.2  NaN
#29:  FYS  957206 4.0 4.40 4.0 NaN 4.0 4.40 4.0 4.2 4.0  3.8  4.4
#30:  FYS  957759 3.8 4.40 4.4 4.4 3.8 4.00 3.2 3.2 3.0  4.2  4.6
#31:  FYS  959200 3.0 3.40 NaN NaN 3.2 3.00 NaN 4.0 NaN  4.2  NaN
#32:  FYS  962490 NaN 3.80 4.2 4.2 4.2 4.60 NaN 3.6 1.0  3.2  NaN
#33:  FYS  968728 3.6 3.80 3.6 3.4 3.4 3.00 1.0 3.0 3.0  1.6  1.6
#34:  FYS  969005 NaN 3.60 4.6 4.4 NaN  NaN 4.4 4.6 NaN  4.6  4.6
#35:  FYS  971179 4.4 4.80 4.4 NaN 4.4 4.25 4.2 4.8 NaN  NaN  5.0
#36:  FYS  976863 NaN 4.40 5.0 3.8 NaN  NaN 3.6 3.6 NaN  4.0  NaN
#37:  FYS  981621 NaN 4.80 4.6 NaN 5.0 4.20 3.8 4.2 NaN  5.0  5.0
#38:  FYS  952797 3.6  NaN NaN 4.0 4.4 3.60 4.0 4.2 NaN  4.0  4.0
#39:  FYS  965873 3.4 4.75 5.0 5.0 4.0 3.80 1.4 2.2 1.6  3.4  NaN
#40:  FYS  967416 4.2  NaN 4.2 NaN 4.2 4.40 4.6 5.0 NaN  NaN  NaN
#41:  FYS  975424 NaN 4.00 3.4 NaN NaN  NaN 2.8 NaN NaN  3.6  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! 
Is there any way to keep the Type of student as a column as well? It tells me what year the student is in (senior =SNR, first year=FYR.

Comment: @Bailey added that too

Answer (score 6):

Use [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Student) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)), -`ï..Question`, -Type, -Student)
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 41 × 12
   Student   Rt1   Rt2   Rt3   Rt4   Rt5   Rt6   Rt7   Rt8   Rt9  Rt10  Rt11
     <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   789331   3.6   3.8   4.0   4.2   3.4   2.4   3.0   3.2   3.2   3.6   4.0
2   796882   NaN   4.4   4.0   4.0   2.8   3.6   2.8   1.4   2.2   2.0   4.2
3   805933   4.8   4.0   4.0   3.6   3.2   3.2   3.2   3.2   NaN   NaN   3.2
4   826523   4.4   4.2   4.2   4.4   4.6   4.6   NaN   4.6   NaN   4.2   4.2
5   827911   NaN   4.2   3.6   NaN   3.4   3.4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
6   830271   NaN   4.6   4.8   5.0   5.0   4.4   4.8   NaN   5.0   NaN   5.0
7   831487   NaN   4.4   4.2   4.6   4.4   NaN   4.2   4.6   4.8   4.4   4.6
8   832929   3.8   3.8   3.8   4.0   3.6   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
9   834598   NaN   5.0   3.8   4.0   4.2   4.0   4.0   NaN   NaN   4.0   4.2
10  836364   NaN   4.0   4.0   4.0   3.6   3.2   3.6   3.6   3.4   3.4   4.0
# ... with 31 more rows
```

### Update: fixed all the `NaN` output

```
library(dplyr)

# Custom `mean` function to return NA if the mean is NaN
#  This occurs if you try to take the mean of an empty set 
#  (i.e. when all of the elements are NA and na.rm = TRUE is selected
fmean <- function(x) {
  m <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  ifelse(is.nan(m), NA, m)
}

df %>% 
  group_by(Student) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(fmean), -`ï..Question`, -Type, -Student)
```